# DIV without padding "higher" than its contents

Tags: html, css, height

I have a `div` containing only an image with a height of 400px. The `div` has no padding but it's height is 406px causing an ugly grey 6px horizontal stripe below its `img`.

The reason for the grey `background` is that comparable `div`s may contain a caption beneath their `img`.

What causes the extra 6px and how can I get rid of it?

P.s. I'm aware the HTML markup is not semantic/HTML5 but I'd rather not change it.

The basic markup is

```
<body>
<div>
    <div class='img w960'>
        <img src='timg-960-480.png' alt=''>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The CSS for this example is

```
body>div{
font-size:20px;
width:26em;
margin:5em auto;
text-align:justify;
}

div.img{
border:0px solid #fff;
border-radius:.5em;
background:#ddd;
margin:1em 0;
width:1px;
overflow:hidden;
display:table;
}

div.w960{
position:relative;
left:-7em;
}

div.w960 img{
width:40em;
}


div.img h3{
margin:0;
padding:1em;
font-size:20px;
font-style:italic;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always solve this problem by setting the image's display property to block (`display: block;`).

Comment: For this case it has the benefit that I don't need to correct the `line-height` for my `h3` img captions. With the current structure there's no downsides to `display:block` either :-D

Answer (score 5):

Set `line-height: 0` on your `div.img`. This will affect the image caption `h3` but you can correct that with an extra CSS line. The image is set inline and sits on the text baseline.

```
body>div{
font-size:20px;
width:26em;
margin:5em auto;
text-align:justify;
}

div.img{
border:0px solid #fff;
border-radius:.5em;
background:#ddd;
margin:1em 0;
width:1px;
overflow:hidden;
display:table;
line-height: 0;
}

div.w960{
position:relative;
left:-7em;
}

div.w960 img{
width:40em;
}


div.img h3{
margin:0;
padding:1em;
font-size:20px;
font-style:italic;
}
```